# Legend formatting when at top or bottom of Google Chart

Tags: google-visualization

I've got a chart where the legend consists of URLs (there could be many)

I'd like to arrange them in a vertical list or grid and get rid of < >, but can't seem to work out how.

I've had a look through the docs but nothing stands out, any suggestions?

[image: example chart]

Comment: From the source it appears there's a legend.maxlines option but that doesn't quite work out right - now get 3 entries on first row, one on second but some on first row are truncated

Comment: The easiest way to do this may be to make a manual legend and use javascript to handle the interaction independently (basically to create custom javascript to handle the legend interaction so you have more control over formatting). Depending on your needs, the code will vary wildly, but legend formatting is horribly finnicky in Google Charts right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this on your code:

```
var options = {
        legend: { position: 'top', maxLines: '6'},
        vAxis: {format:'###,###'}
        };
```

Hope to help!