# How to change the layout of google pie chart with label?

Tags: javascript, graph, google-visualization

Hi I need to modify google chart. Where the labels are to be at bottom with two columns.

What i have :

[image]

What i Need:

[image]

I tried Label : {position: 'bottom', maxLines: 5}

but it says maxlines only works with position : top . 
Please let me know if this is possible.

Thanks

Comment: From [API doc: legend.maxLines](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart?hl=pt-PT), currently it does not support vertically stacking the legend. Related question: [Legend formatting when at top or bottom of Google Chart](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16361401/legend-formatting-when-at-top-or-bottom-of-google-chart)

Comment: Workaround: Move SVG rect and text but it is error-prone. In `.draw` method, use `legend: {position: 'top', maxLines: 5}, chartArea: {width: '36%'}`, Then use css `<style>
      #visualization div div svg g g rect, #visualization div div svg g g text {
        transform: translate(0px,320px);
        -ms-transform: translate(0px,320px); /* IE 9 */
        -webkit-transform: translate(0px,320px); /* Safari and Chrome */
        -o-transform: translate(0px,320px); /* Opera */
        -moz-transform: translate(0px,320px); /* Firefox */
      }
    </style>`

Comment: Thanks for that Ivan Chau... but the prob still persists.

Comment: The legend customization options in the Visualization API won't support what you want to do, but you can turn off the legend entirely (set the `legend.position` option to `'none'`) and build a custom legend in HTML.

Comment: And at any rate, pie charts are far inferior to bar charts for stuff like this. I recommend switching to a bar chart, since pie charts with more than 3 slices are impossible to read and may as well be data tables for all the good the visualization does.